# Как найти пост, содержащий в контенте словосочетание?

Tags: wordpress

Нужно найти посты, заголовок и/или контент которого содержит точное словосочетание состоящее из двух и более слов. Пробовал так:

```
$args = array
(
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_type'         => 'post',
    's'                 => 'множество чудес',
    'exact'             => true
);

$posts = get_posts($args);
```

Так вообще ничего не находит. Без параметра 'exact' находит, но при этом много не нужного находит (находит слова 'множество' и 'чудес' в разных местах контента, что не есть хорошо).

Comment: Где найти? Кто ищет? Юзер на сайте или какова цель поиска?

Comment: Найти среди всех постов. На странице нужно вывести посты содержащие фразу

Comment: Т.е. юзер на сайте. Уточни это в вопросе..

Comment: У меня есть произвольное поле поста, в него записано словосочетание (ключевое слово). И на основании этого словосочетания мне нужно вывести посты у которых в контенте или заголовке есть это словосочетание.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поиск в кавычках решит задачу.

Comment: Уточни, мне нужно через get_post или WP_Query решить эту задачу

Comment: спасибо решил эту задачу. Подскажи где можно почитать про эти доб. символы?

Comment: Про какие добавочные? Кавычки просто говорят скрипту поиска, что это одна поисковая строка.

Comment: а что еще можно подставлять. Например если перед словом поставить минус, то это слово будет исключаться. Хотелось бы иметь полную картину.

Comment: Этого вроде нет в ядре. Но когда-то встречались плагины расширенного поиска.

Comment: Про минус я вычитал в самом кодексе https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Search_Parameter. А вот про кавычки ничего не сказано.